# Fill form fields from select option in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form in which I have to add multiple products. These products are added one by one by clicking the button. Here is the code for the same:

order.php

```
<script>
    $('#addOrderProduct').click(function(){
      var j = 1;
      var dataString = "j="+j;
      $.ajax({
        url: "addProdToOrder.php",
        type: "post",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response){
          $('.dynamics').append(response);
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

This is the script to add rows to the table dynamically.

addProdToOrder.php

```
<?php
<tr style="text-align: center;" id="products">
  <td><?php echo $j; ?></td>
  <td><select class="form-control" name="code" id="productID" style="width: 429px;">
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `product`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<option id='".$row['code']."' value='".$row['code']."'>".$row['pname']."</option>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="hsnNo" id="hsnNo" readonly></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" readonly></td>
  <td class="coljoin"><input type="number" format="2" name="amount"></td>
  <td>
    <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
?>
```

Now, once a row is added, I want to set the form values based on the select option. I have implemented the code but it is running only for one row. I want the same code to run for multiple rows in the same form. Here is the code:

order.php

```
<script>
$('#productID').change(function(){
  var code = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'code='+code;

  $.ajax({
    url: "getProdDets.php",
    type: "post",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(response){
      var Vals = JSON.parse(response);
      $("input[name='hsnNo']").val(Vals.hsnNo);
      $("input[name='qty']").val(Vals.qty);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

The form should look like this: [Multiple Row addition on Add Product Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPwUa.png)

The PHP page to which the ajax is calling to set the form fields is:

getProdDets.php

```
<?php
require('../config.php');
$code = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : '';
if(!empty($_POST)){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `code`='$code'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo  json_encode(array("hsnNo"=>$row['hsn'], "qty"=>$row['quantity']));
  }
}

}

?>
```

What should I do to set the values of the field for every row?

Comment: It is almost impossible to help you. We see no working example, we see no content of `addProdToOrder.php` response, I do not know even what works and what is wrong, it is unclear. Please try to create a JSFiddle with fake ajax responses if necessary.

Comment: Here's the deal:
I click on a button to call ajax to insert a table row. Once the table row is inserted into the table, I have a select input field in the row along with other fields. Now, Based on the option I select from the select list, I want to set the details in the rest of the fields